# is there any way to set my system Ip which is in LAN (not Localhost) as the Https protocol?

Tags: https, localhost, progressive-web-apps, service-worker, service-worker-config

[image]

The project that I'm working on, is PWA and for testing, I need https protocol.
I have created a site in IIS in my system and I made the HTTPS settings.
when I browse https://localhost:my-Port/ everything is OK. and it knows the service-worker.
On the other, I got my system Ip that is 172.20.10:my-Port.
But when I call 172.20.10:my-Port from my devices which are connected to one Wifi, the devices don't know service-worker, because the protocol is not secure.

because of my system config, I cant use emulators, and also because my project is MVC, I can't use web Server chrome extension or use npm-run in vs code to give me valid and secure Ips.

Sorry about the bad grammar.

Answer (score 0):

You can map any host name to the required ip using `hosts` file. Then issue certificate for that name and use it by your server.

You also can use your computer name (see `COMPUTERNAME`, `USERDOMAIN`, `USERDNSDOMAIN` env variables). You will still need to have a valid certificate for that name.